# Generalized Helly theorem for $t$-intersecting families

Tags: co.combinatorics, hypergraph, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-set-theory

Given a family $\mathcal{F}$ of sets over ground set $X$, let $\tau(\mathcal{F})$ be the **transversal number** (aka blocking number), that is the cardinality of the smallest set of points $E \subseteq X$ such that every set in $\mathcal{F}$ meets $E$.

Lovasz (Problem 13.25 in his Problems & Exercises books) has proved that if $F$ is an $r$-uniform family of sets that every $k$ sets in $F$ intersect, then:
$$
\tau(\mathcal{F}) \leq \frac{r-1}{k-1}+1.
$$

I wonder whether it is possible to strengthen the conclusion if we assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is $k$-wise $t$-intersecting (that is, every $k$ sets in $\mathcal{F}$ intersect in at least $t$ points).

I can obtain the following by mimicking the proof, but I feel there ought to be a better result somewhere:
$$
\tau(\mathcal{F}) \leq \frac{r-t}{k-1}+1.
$$

Comment: I have a friend who wrote a masters thesis on Helly's type theorems, maybe you can find something there?
http://www2.math.su.se/gemensamt/grund/exjobb/matte/2008/rep2/report.pdf

Comment: I think I do not understand the question. It seems to me that if I duplicate the points so that newly I have $t$ copies of each point, then the condition that every $k$ sets intersect becomes the condition that every $k$ sets intersect in at least $t$ points. But this "duplication" does not change the transversal number (intersection pattern).

Comment: @MartinTancer But you also change $r$ in the process, don't you? The sets become bigger.

Comment: Thank you, now I think I understand. (It is easy to confuse "r sets" and "r-sets".)

Comment: @MartinTancer Sorry for the confusion - I modified the text to be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best possible bound. If $\mathcal F$ consists of every $r$-set of a set with $r+\frac{r-t}{k-1}$ elements, then it is still $k$-wise $t$-intersecting.